# is there a way i can fix this invalid module name error?

Tags: java, javafx, error-handling, compiler-errors

Since the pandemic started. I chose to learn java and this is the first time i'm having an error i can't rectify for more than three(3) days now. this is the code

```html
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <Button GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" text="Refresh">
        <graphic>
            <ImageView>
                <Image url="@/toolbarButtonGraphics/general/About16.gif"/>
            </ImageView>
        </graphic>
    </Button>
</GridPane>
```

I keep getting this error below

***"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\Alt\Documents\jlfgr-1_0.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jlfgr.1.0: Invalid module name: '1' is not a Java identifier"***

after i have added the jlfgr.1.0 file in the the projects. please i need somebody's help. Thank you very much. I really appreciate.

Comment: Hi, please provide the code that is producing the error.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62765500/edit) the post instead of posting the information in the comments.  It's much easier to read.

Comment: @stdunbar i just edited the post with the code. This is the first time i'm actually using stackoverflow and i should be getting used to it soon. Thanks

Comment: @fose i just edited the post with the code. This is the first time i'm actually using stackoverflow and i should be getting used to it soon. Thanks you. I appreciate if i could get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can locate the `module-info.java` file, try to:

1. Rename the jar file to something like just `jlfgr.jar`
2. In the `module-info.java` file, add the following sentence:

   ```
   requires jlfgr;
   ```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. It has worked and i'm so glad. I appreciate

Comment: you'r welcome mate