# Invalid module name error when runing the client

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Like the title says  every time I try to run the client I get this error
I am fairly new to coding so excuse me if the error is really obvious
I am using Intellij with JRE java 17

Feel free to ask if you need any more information

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: : Invalid module name: '' is not a Java identifier
at java.base/jdk.internal.module.Checks.requireModuleName(Checks.java:59)
at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$Builder.<init>(ModuleDescriptor.java:1515)
at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.newAutomaticModule(ModuleDescriptor.java:2395)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@0.9.54/cpw.mods.jarhandling.impl.SimpleJarMetadata.descriptor(SimpleJarMetadata.java:13)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@0.9.54/cpw.mods.jarhandling.impl.Jar.computeDescriptor(Jar.java:47)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@0.9.54/cpw.mods.cl.JarModuleFinder$JarModuleReference.<init>(JarModuleFinder.java:50)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@0.9.54/cpw.mods.cl.JarModuleFinder.lambda$new$0(JarModuleFinder.java:28)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@0.9.54/cpw.mods.cl.JarModuleFinder.<init>(JarModuleFinder.java:29)
at cpw.mods.securejarhandler@0.9.54/cpw.mods.cl.JarModuleFinder.of(JarModuleFinder.java:43)
at cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher@0.1.17/cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher.main(BootstrapLauncher.java:81)
```

Comment: JavaScript is not the same as Java. Use correct tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a way i can fix this invalid module name error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765500/is-there-a-way-i-can-fix-this-invalid-module-name-error)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.