# How to solve the following error as Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I am running my selenium program after 2 weeks and following error occurs. how to resolve following?

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

error while running the program.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a way i can fix this invalid module name error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765500/is-there-a-way-i-can-fix-this-invalid-module-name-error)